# Log4J 2 configuration monitoring and bitwise comparison

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, java.util.concurrent

A colleague pointed out the following snippet from the [Log4J 2.3 code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=logging-log4j2.git;a=blob;f=log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/FileConfigurationMonitor.java;h=38f64cf5a6571de5f78551e52a797c7f19866bd8;hb=2f6b93c05e38e042b9a018a2526182c2f5b0a9dd#l77):

```
/**
  * Called to determine if the configuration has changed.
  */
 @Override
 public void checkConfiguration() {
     final long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
     if (((counter.incrementAndGet() & MASK) == 0) && (current >= nextCheck)) {
         LOCK.lock();
         try {
             nextCheck = current + intervalSeconds;
             if (file.lastModified() > lastModified) {
                 lastModified = file.lastModified();
                 for (final ConfigurationListener listener : listeners) {
                     final Thread thread = new Thread(new ReconfigurationWorker(listener, reconfigurable));
                     thread.setDaemon(true);
                     thread.start();
                 }
             }
         } finally {
             LOCK.unlock();
         }
     }
```

Where `counter` is an `AtomicInteger` field, `MASK` is set to `0x0f` and `nextCheck` is `long`.

As far as I can understand, this method checks whether or not to reload the configuration, but does so only when the `counter`'s value is divisible by 16 *and* the next configuration check period has elapsed.

Why is this bitwise AND there?

Given the `incrementAndGet` is synchronised for the `counter` instance could it be considered a "cheap" throttling mechanism? Or perhaps the number of times `checkConfiguration` is called during the "typical" `nextCheck` period is way more than necessary, thus the bitwise AND is there as a performance trick (again, throttling?).

Comment: "perhaps the number of times checkConfiguration is called [...] is way more than necessary" - I think the code implies just that. Need to find out where/why this method is called. Obviously, they are also prepared for concurrent executions of `checkConfiguration`.

Comment: I think the `counter` increment is partially a synchronisation concern: allows calls on the same instance to perform the next update check in a threadsafe manner, as well as reducing the calls to subsequent block (which is locked by a `ReentrantLock` instance.

Comment: I think I found it: `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(String, Level, Marker, Message, Throwable)` unconditionally calls `checkConfiguration()`, so that'd make a *lot* of calls.

Comment: Good find! I thought it'd be called from the logging layer. So it's likely to be a throttling mechanism.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a throttling mechanism. Seems to reduce the "load" on the `LOCK` during the short time period before `nextCheck` is updated. Interesting, though, that you'd need a certain frequency of logging to make it work reasonably. If you'd only log one message every minute, you might be surprised that the new configuration is not effective until 16 minutes later!

Comment: The fact that this runs synchronously upon every logging statement also explains why this routine has to be thread-safe, and why the actual job of re-reading the config is then deferred to a new thread - you want your logging statement to be as non-invasive as possible, and implicitly reading and parsing a file from who-knows-where during a logging statement is not exactly what one expects.

Comment: By the way, I once faced some trouble when I used code like that `if (file.lastModified() > lastModified)` - People would sometimes restore a previous copy of the file and my code wouldn't pick up the change because the modified timestamp did not *increase* but rather decrease. So, `file.lastModified() != lastModified` should be the safer way.

Comment: And while we're at it, `((counter.incrementAndGet() & MASK) == 0) && (current >= nextCheck)` is not really clever performance-wise. As it is, both `System.currentTimeMillis()` *and* `counter.incrementAndGet()` are called *every* time. That's not really necessary. `(current >= nextCheck) && ((counter.incrementAndGet() & MASK) == 0)` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a throttling mechanism. In Log4j 2.3 this method was called for every log event. The bitwise AND means the remainder of the check is only executed once every 16 log events.

As noticed in the comments, it is debatable how effective this is in terms of performance gain. The call to `System::currentTimeMillis` is not free, and under heavy contention `AtomicLong::incrementAndGet` performance also [degrades](https://minddotout.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/java-8-concurrency-longadder/).

Since Log4j 2.5 the above code no longer exists (see [LOG4J2-89](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-89)). It has been replaced by a [WatchManager](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/f3e876a0fefd5d77c6f278b073bfa15df7971c44/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/WatchManager.java) class that monitors whether the configuration file has been modified in a background thread.